# Displaying Output in IOS Applications

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

What is the best way to display some text data as output in an iphone application.
I am able retrieve a set of details about a particular car in my application.How to display them in a nice way.Currently i am using Labels.

Is there any better way.. I am new to ios programming

Comment: major data display as in UITableview with image remaining are navigated to more details with some good animation

Comment: Uitextview maybe? Allows use of formatted text so suitable for formatted report type output.  Uses RTF (rich text format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UITableView Custom Cell with UILabels and UIImages for cars, please refer WWDC 2013 videos `Building User interfaces for iOS7` and `Best practices for great iOS UI Design` https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ for reference and http://pttrns.com/categories/20-content-screen

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the *structure* of the text data that you want to show.

For *plain text*, a `UILabel` is good. You can set the `numberOfLines` property if you want to show more than one line, or unlimited number of lines (set to 0).

For *rich text*, you can use a `UITextView`.

For *HTML*, `UIWebView` gives you Safari's rendering behavior and support.

For *one-column tabular data*, the classical `UITableView` is good. It's best for hierarchical information, that is, it is appropriate for when you have to present the user a bunch of records (maybe retrieved from some database) and you group them by some criteria (sections, or "group by" in SQL terminology). Each of those records may have additional information that you show when the user taps on the corresponding table view cell.

If you want to show *multi-column tabular data*, or any other complex layout that `UITableView` does not support, you can use a `UICollectionView` (available from iOS6+).

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableView, with custom cells for car image and other details.

Answer (score 0):

Table View is best options for you.
  Create  a UITableView And add an UIImageView and UILabel for details of car....